# Choosing a MongoDB Shard Key that benefits read performance

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I've read in many places that selecting timestamp is a poor choice of a Shard Key due to it creating hotspots upon insert.  If I add another attribute or two to the Shard Key, it would create a more even distribution but the only other attribute(s) that might make sense are not the attributes used for querying.  How important is that for squeezing the most out of read performance?

**Sample Document**

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId>,
  user_id: <ObjectId>,
  _p:  <6-10 possible values>,
  ts:  <UNIX timestamp>,
  a:   'lorem ipsum',
  b:   <Array of ObjectId, can be null/empty>,
  ...,
  z:   'xyz'
}
```

This collection is typically queried one of two ways:

1. by user_id (sorted by timestamp)
2. by b and timestamp <- almost always used by Aggregation Framework operations

Would a Shard Key like one of the following be a good choice if I'm looking to have good/better read performance (write gains are secondary for my use case):

```
{
  user_id:     1,
  timestamp:   1
}
```

or

```
{
  user_id:    1,
  _p:         1,
  timestamp:  1
}
```

or

```
{
  _p:         1,
  timestamp:  1
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If timestamp in your data rarely changes, maybe timestamp in shard key is ok.
You can read [the docs for shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-high-availability/#shard-keys-and-cluster-availability). Good idea - using for shard key fields which "to ensure that MongoDB will be able to distribute data evenly among shards". And then create index on timestamp. If your timestamp field change often (insert data with new timestamp), using it for shard key is bad idea, because mongo can't normally distribute your data.

Comment: Timestamp by itself (or any monotonically increasing value such as an ObjectID) is a *very poor* choice of shard key. This will lead to a "hot shard" performance problem where all data is being written to the shard with the highest timestamp value as new data arrives. MongoDB 2.4+ has a [hashed shard index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#hashed-shard-keys) which can be used to uniformly distribute values, but that comes at the expense of distributing both writes *and* reads.

Answer (score 0):

At the first try to shard only by users. If this is not enough add _p. When we talk about sharding try to imagine a library with multiple buildings. And think how you can put all books in all buldings. Timestamp not best solution for this work I think. Find unmutable data (for example you set it one time when docunent is creating) and shard by these fields.